# Nginx config to preventing non-browser requests to domain/IP

Tags: nginx, configuration, http

Having recently installed django 1.6 on a server hosting several django based sites, I'm getting a lot of errors for "ERROR: Invalid HTTP_HOST header". This is [a known 'feature'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).

The problem is that requests are coming in from non-browsers which are triggering the error, but not being forwarded as per the nginx config (Nginx 1.6.0).

For example, I've setup a default server (which is also first in the config files):

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    location / {
        return 403 "Forbidden";
    }
}
```

This works for a browser (when I test it), however, somehow this is being bypassed by random bots (and flooding my email). For example, requests to the IP address or to `autodiscover.mydomain.com` (probably an outlook/exchange thing?)

I have also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149435/avoiding-djangos-500-error-for-not-allowed-host-with-nginx), but to no avail because they are bypassing the default config.

Is there a means of preventing this type of access?

Comment: Is your host IPv6 connected? That would be the only way I can think of that would not match your default server with an empty host header, since listen 80 is IPv4 only. Well, aside from other IPv4 addresses.

Comment: No, it isn't coming in on IPV6. Still debugging between other jobs, it's a pain!

Comment: What does your ALLOWED_HOSTS look like and what is the nginx logged http host header?

Comment: The issue is that the request is hitting the wrong Django config, so ALLOWED_HOSTS is not relevant. The logged header? Um, not sure, I will check. I'm not sure it is logged at all, as it is slipping through site configs.

Comment: You can log the host by adding $http_host to the log format for the relevant access log.

Comment: We tried that, but nginx doesn't appear to be routing requests to the correct site. It seems to be a bug in nginx, we're going to try updating that and see if it changes. If so I'll create an answer for that.

Comment: Ok, so you know the Django server it's hitting, because of the mails. You know the server configuration and location block that belongs to that Django site. Even in that location block, you can specify an access log, that includes the $http_host variable. If it is a value that belongs to a different site, then this sounds like a bug. If it is a value that matches for instance a wildcard, then there is a problem in your config. That's why I focus on getting the value of the host header.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to deny bots from doing random scans. You can do this by checking the referrer.

There is a great article at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-webserver-security.html

In particular, look at #10 - Allow Access To Your Domain Only

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that would work in the default config, rather than having to lock down each vhost. #11 appeared that it might work, but didn't, leading me to think #10 would not work either.